# Bootstrap "dropdown-menu" is scrolling to top?

Tags: razor, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used Bootstrap in my  MVC4 application. I am trying to implement Action dropdown menu for "Edit" and "delete". When click on "Action" menu, it is scrolling to page to and adding `#` to url.

```
<td>

   @if (model.Source == "self")
   { 
       <div class="btn-group">
       <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
             Action
       <span class="caret"></span>
       </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       @{
          @Html.TryPartial("_actions", model)                            
          var routevalues = model.GetIdValue();  
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", routevalues)</li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", routevalues)</li>
         }
       </ul>
       </div>
   }

 </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include    `@Scripts.Render("~/js")` in layouts page.